# multiplying all elements in an array by an outside number?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I need to multiple all the values in an array by 3000 which in turn would create a new array that I will use to subtract from another array. I've tried to create a separate method that would do that for me but all I got back in the multiplied array was a bunch of numbers and symbols strangely?

here is the code that I wrote

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{    
    int numberOfTaxpayers = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter how many users you would like to calculate taxes for: ");
    int[] usernumChild = new int[numberOfTaxPayers];
    for (int i = 0; i < usernumChild.length; i++)
    {
        usernumChild[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of children for user "+ (i+1) +": "));
    }//this for loop finds out the number of children per user so we can later multiply each input by 3000 to create an array that determine dependency exemption for each user
int[] depndExemp = multiply(usernumChild, 3000);//this was the calling of the multiply method... somewhere here is the error!!
}//end main method 
public static int[] multiply(int[] children, int number)
{
    int array[] = new int[children.length];
    for( int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
    {
       children[i] = children[i] * number;
    }//end for
    return array;
}//this is the method that I was shown in a previous post on how to create return an array in this the dependency exemption array but when I tested this by printing out the dependency array all I received were a jumble of wrong numbers.
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'a new array that I will use to subtract from another array'?

Comment: @Lutz Horn I haven't included that part in yet, but what I will have to do is take the dependency array (multiplying children by 3000 for each input) then subtract from another array that contains the gross income for each user which will lead to another array being created under net income... for some reason our instructor wants an array for each data type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example you're multiplying your children array but returning your new array. You need to multiply your new array by your children array.

```
1 public static int[] multiply(int[] children, int number)
2 {
3     int array[] = new int[children.length];
4     for( int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
5     {
6         array[i] = children[i] * number;
7     }//end for
8     return array;
9 }
```

The reason you're getting strange symbols is because you are returning uninitialized values. The array itself is allocated at line 3 but at this point each index of the array has not been initialized so we don't really know what values are in there.

Comment: where would I be initializing the return value? Would I be initially changing the second method?

Comment: Ill clarify the answer for you

Comment: Ok I understand now thanks, but how would I get the contents of usernumChild over to the other method? I thought declaring it in multiply(usernumChild, 3000) would do that? Is it possible for me to then just get rid of the second method and do the algorithm in the main so I don't have to pass array around? simplicity is key at the moment.

Comment: Your correct that you __should__ do everything in one loop. Since you can do all the work at once you won't need to iterate the loop multiple times for each operation. If you weren't going for _efficiency_ and instead _ease of reading_ you may break each operation into it's own method but I don't recommend this.

Answer (score 3):

Using Java 8 streams it can be as simple as:

```
public static int[] multiply(int[] children, int number) {

    return Arrays.stream(children).map(i -> i*number).toArray();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You really don't have to create new array in your method (and you are also returning the old one without any change). So just do

```
public static int[] multiply(int[] children, int number) {
    for(int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        children[i] = children[i] * number;
    }
    return children;
}
```

Comment: Can I do the multiplication without creating a new method? I would like to try and keep this program as clean and simple as possible. At this point with 36 hours left to work on it and much more being needed to accomplish an end result looks bleak to say the least!

Comment: Yes, you can but it's better to have multiple methods then one huge one so this is a correct design. Rule of thumb is that each method should fit to the screen

Answer (score 1):

You need to Change

```
children[i] = children[i] * number;
```

to

```
 array[i] = children[i] * number;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
children[i] = children[i] * number;
```

Should be changed to

```
array[i] = children[i] * number;
```

Considering you are returning `array`, not `children`.

Answer (score 0):

In your second for loop it should be :

```
for(int i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
       array[i] = children[i] * number;
}//end for
```

Also make sure that all values of `children[i]` are inferior than `((2^31 - 1)/number) +1`

Comment: hmm I tried that and still I get a system.print of   [I@4a3a6e5c

Comment: @prodo This means that you're printing the reference of the int array you created. For printing your array, you can make a for loop and print each values or use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));`

Comment: I would have to go the route of creating a loop, so you suggest creating an extended for loop? placing the values of     depndExemp into a    for(int reprint : depndExemp){    System.out.println(reprint)}

Comment: @prodo If it's a one dimensional array, yes